For Ramban, who holds that there is a commandment to control and settle Eretz Yisrael, is it bounded by the Jordan or by the Euphrates?
Ramban holds (e.g., Bamidbar 33:53, Devarim 11:24, mitzvos that Rambam neglected to mention #4) that there is a positive biblical commandment to conquer and settle the land which is incumbent upon Israel for all time.
Is that land bounded by the Jordan river, as demarcated in Bamidbar, the source of the commandment, or does it extend all the way to the Euphrates, as depicted in Devarim?
(Interestingly, in ShM and Devarim, when Ramban mentions the pesukim from Devarim, which include פרת, he omits mention of it, I'm unsure if it is intentional or not.)

@b a Knew something looked off, couldn't pin it down, thanks!

Meshech Chochma somewhere in Devarim says that it applies to Transjordan as well, and thus Moshe fulfilled the (Ramban's) mitzva

@AKA Ya, thanks, it's here: משך חכמה דברים י"א:ל"א
דקיימו גם בארץ סיחון ועוג מצוה זו, שזהו האמורי מה שאמר והורשתם את הארץ וישבתם בה, וא"כ מדוע הי' משה מבקש לכנוס לארץ, ודאי כל זמן שלא הי' כבוש וחלוק בארץ היו מקיימים בזה ישיבת א"י. וזה פשוט. Not sure if he means to extend it past the land of Sichon and Og and also it looks like even that falls away after the conquest of the main land . .

the ramban says by D'varim 11:24 that its only land of 7 nations, which seems to exclude the people living all the way to the Euphrates

@Mordechai Where do you see that? He writes רמב"ן דברים י"א:כ"ד
ומן המדבר והלבנון ועד הים האחרון יהיה גבולכם – שאתם חייבים לכבשו ולאבד משם העמים, that pasuk also includes מן הנהר נהר פרת in between והלבנון and ועד.

היה חיב להוריש כל שבעת הגוים בתחלה ואחרי כן אם ירצה ילך אל ארץ אחרת

@Mordechai I hear. How do you then read the part I quoted?

I assumed it was yam hamelach but the oz vhadar note is "ומשמע מדברי רבינו שסובר שהגבולות של ארץ ישראל הגיעו עד נהר פרת. וראה בהעמק דבר שדייק מדברי הרמב"ם שהגבולות האלה הם העתידיים לבוא, וראה חזון איש שביעית ג סק"ל" this sounds like it's a 2 step process. Then was only 7 nations, in future till Euphrates

@Mordechai It is mentioned in the context of the mitzvah of conquering it and vanquishing the nations

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The Ramban (D'varim 19:8) writes that the commandment to Moshe (& Yehoshua) was to only conquer the 7 nations in Israel proper and all commandments of the Torah are only for these 7. He then writes in the days of Mashiach (here he quotes D'varim 30:6 and he explains there that this means Mashiach) we will get all 10 nations promised to Avraham, ie to the Euphrates.

Deleted my comments. Let us continue this discussion in chat.
